# intercept http request using mitmproxy

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mitmproxy

I am trying to intercept all the http/https request from my android device by using `mitmproxy` on my Ubuntu pc.

Both these devices are on the same network , but running `mitmproxy -T --host` in the terminal remains blank even after I have made multiple requests with my android device.

For your info, I did set the Gateway in my android device to the ip adress of my Ubuntu pc and have added the mitmproxy certifacte (.cer) file to the device. Intersetingly, when I try 127.0.0.1:8080 in my browser from my Ubuntu pc, i see multiple GET request stream in the  `mitmproxy` console, such as :

```
**GET 127.0.0.1:8080 ← 502: Server disconnect.**
```

Comment: set the proxy of your android device to the ip address of your ubuntu pc.

Comment: i did set the proxy to the ip adres of my pc but that resulted in some unexpected errors 1. every address (say www.google.com) in the browser returns error .      access forbindden! and the url becomes google.co.in/xampp on its own  2. google play store crashes every now and then

Comment: I haven't used mitmproxy, but I used Charles proxy and it worked great. Charles is great too, may be you could try that.

Comment: charles can't be used to intercept http request from my android device..can it be??

Comment: yes it can be. just run charles on your pc and set the correct ip and port where charles is running(default is 8888) on your android device.

Comment: yeah it seems to work! bt any idea how do i get it to intercept requests made through android app?it doesnt seem to intercept that or may be m lacking somewhere!.

Comment: any http/https requests made through android app is intercepted. maybe other traffics are not intercepted. what's app didnt worked for me.. but other apps that made api calls were working fine with mine.